# How can I append to a file using dd?

Tags: sudo, root

On Linux systems, I can append to a system file like this:

```
echo "# New data" | sudo dd of=/etc/config_file conv=notrunc oflag=append
```

But the dd command under OS X doesn't have the `oflag` option. Is this possible under OS X?

Notes:

1. I need root access.
2. I'm not asking for alternative solutions, I'm asking if dd has the capability.

Comment: Install brew and brew/coreutils which provide (GNU) dd - linked as gdd to /usr/local/bin.

Answer (score 3):

You can `seek` to the end of the target file:

```
sudo echo "# New data" |
    dd of=/etc/config_file conv=notrunc bs=1 seek=$(stat -f "%z" /etc/config_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you are using `dd` rather than output redirection?

The following will work:

```
echo "# New data" >> /etc/config_file
```

The `>>` means add to the end of file if it exists, otherwise create a new file.

Comment: Note `sudo` for root access.

Comment: Just add `sudo` in front of the whole line shown.

Comment: Nope, that won't work, either. In any case, I can come up with alternatives. The question is specifically about dd.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried what you mention above , sadly it is not appending the output file as expected. But you can do below method,

**First Create temporary file and later use dd command**

**Create** a **temp_file** and **redirect** all data/output you want to write to that file and later you can do

```
sudo dd if=/temp_file_path of=/etc/config_file conv=notrunc
```